# How can I load the image from web, and show it in the view as soon as I get some data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

How can I load the image from web, and put it into a UIImageViewController as soon as I get some data and the data may not be completely downloaded.

In other words， when I get a part data of the image and show a part of the image in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I have done earlier the same thing(Mutiple request downloads simultaniously) with the help of ASIHTTP Wrapper.

header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASINetworkQueue.h"

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {
    ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue;

    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView1;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView3;
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressIndicator;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *accurateProgress;
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *imageProgressIndicator1;
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *imageProgressIndicator2;
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *imageProgressIndicator3;
    IBOutlet UILabel *imageLabel1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *imageLabel2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *imageLabel3;
    IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;
    BOOL failed;

}
```

Implementation file

```
- (IBAction)fetchThreeImages:(id)sender
{
    [imageView1 setImage:nil];
    [imageView2 setImage:nil];
    [imageView3 setImage:nil];

    if (!networkQueue) {
        networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];  
    }
    failed = NO;
    [networkQueue reset];
    [networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressIndicator];
    [networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageFetchComplete:)];
    [networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(imageFetchFailed:)];
    [networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:[accurateProgress isOn]];
    [networkQueue setDelegate:self];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request;
    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/tests/images/small-image.jpg"]];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.png"]];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:imageProgressIndicator1];
    [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request1" forKey:@"name"]];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/tests/images/medium-image.jpg"]] autorelease];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.png"]];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:imageProgressIndicator2];
    [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request2" forKey:@"name"]];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/tests/images/large-image.jpg"]] autorelease];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"3.png"]];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:imageProgressIndicator3];
    [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request3" forKey:@"name"]];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    [networkQueue go];
}


- (void)imageFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[request downloadDestinationPath]];
    if (img) {
        if ([imageView1 image]) {
            if ([imageView2 image]) {
                [imageView3 setImage:img];
            } else {
                [imageView2 setImage:img];
            }
        } else {
            [imageView1 setImage:img];
        }
    }
}

- (void)imageFetchFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if (!failed) {
        if ([[request error] domain] != NetworkRequestErrorDomain || [[request error] code] != ASIRequestCancelledErrorType) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download failed" message:@"Failed to download images" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [alertView show];
        }
        failed = YES;
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask if any problem.

Comment: This is still agreat solution, I've used it as well. But if you are planing your app for the long term, ASIHTTP might not be the best way to go, since it's discontinued. This means, e.g. ARC won't be implemented. Read the blog on http://allseeing-i.com/ before you make a decision. Search for the string 'looking elsewhere'.